# setState is not working properly in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to create a object with multiple object. the data is something like this

`dataList = [{inputFieldId: 1, dataField:{...}, data: '120'}, {inputFieldId: 2, dataField:{...}, data: '120'} ]`

what is want like this.

`res = [{1: '120'}, {2: '120'}]`

i write a code for this but its giving me the last object data only.

```
  constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
  inputValue:{},
  datalist = [],
  }
  }


   async componentWillMount(){
     for(var key in dataList){
        this.setState({
           inputValue: {
             ...this.state.inputValue,
             [dataList[key].inputFieldId]: dataList[key].data
          }
      })
  }     
}
```

`code output = { 2: '120'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a code as follows:

```
constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    inputValue: {},
    datalist = [],
  }
}


async componentWillMount() {
  const inputValues = [];
  for(var key in dataList) {
    inputValues.push({[dataList[key].inputFieldId]: dataList[key].data});
  }
  this.setState({ inputValue: inputValues });
}
```